# Terraform unable to list provider registration status

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to run terraform apply on a folder with a tf file, after running init.

However, I get the error below:

> Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - provider.azurerm: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service
>   principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API,
>   Azure error: resources.ProvidersClien t#List: Failure responding to
>   request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
>   returned an error. Stat us=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The
>   client '17cd0b64-08fb-48db-ad9f-4dd56361bb47' with object id
>   '17cd0b64-08 fb-48db-ad9f-4dd56361bb47' does not have authorization to
>   perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/providers/re ad'
>   over scope '/subscriptions/9a305d25-7f89-43d4-a691-62ad0f63c5c8'."

The tf file has my tenant id, subscription id, all the other required fields, but the error keeps happening. Please advise?

EDIT: Below is my tf file

```js
  provider "azurerm" {
     subscription_id = "****"
     client_id       = "**client_id**"
  client_secret   = "****"
  tenant_id       = "**+*"
}



# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "production" {
  name     = "productiongs"
  location = "West US"
}
```

Comment: You are the 21k user in Stackoverflow, but you ask for question without any details but error message, something else you can provide, such as the codes, how to run the commands, environment variables you set,  and others?

Comment: Did you really post your secret credentials?! If thats the case, please revoke them and audit your setup for any changes done using the given creds.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the Service Principal doesn't have the `Contributor` role assigned to it.

Just go to the **Subscription** in the portal, select **Access Control (IAM)** and **Add** the **Role assignment**, **Contributor** to your Service Principal

[image]

[Or follow these instructions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#3-granting-the-application-access-to-manage-resources-in-your-azure-subscription)

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your terraform setup it's hard to know the exact problem, but I am guessing you are missing your client_id and client_secret.

So your provider would look something like this:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "..."
  client_id       = "..."
  client_secret   = "..."
  tenant_id       = "..."
}
```

More information here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/

Comment: Hmm I have that specified though. I can share the code tonight from home.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the given error message, I would say the given credentials do not have required permissions over the said resources.

```
 perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/providers/read'
 over scope '/subscriptions/9a305d25-7f89-43d4-a691-62ad0f63c5c8'."
```

Did you create your credentials as per given instructions at

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/

Also, from https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/issues/127#issuecomment-226659944

> "To enable the application for use with Azure RM, you now need to
>   switch to the 'New' Portal:" and further. You need to add that app
>   credential to the Azure portal and give permission. Trick is about
>   adding by name manually as "Type in the name of the application added
>   in the 'Classic' Portal. You need to type this as it won't be shown in
>   the user list. Click on the appropriate user in the list and then
>   click Select"

Answer (score 2):

I am getting this from time to time, especially when trying to debug code and repeatedly hitting the API, It seems to solve itself when you leave it for a while.

I speculate whether i am hitting a rule on their API management

Comment: i am getting it from time to time as well... i won't change anything and an apply will run without this error, and then later it will, so i know the principal is good - but can't find out why it happens

Answer (score 0):

I received exactly the same errors when attempting to use terraform with an Azure CLI cloud shell.  Seems the only way to get this to work was by installing terraform on either through logging in to a Virtual Machine/local machine and installing terraform.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after not using Terraform project for a while. What solved the issue was upgrading azurerm provider in the terraform script from 3.0.2 to currently latest 3.87.0:

```
required_providers {
  azurerm = {
    source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    version = "~> 3.87.0"
  }
}
```