# Authorization error during terraform plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy resource in azure using terraform. but when i applied terraform plan, i am getting below error.

I m using service principle for authorization.

```
 terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: resources.ProvidersClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'c087e26a-321f-4f0c-95ae-65b5a40cf514' with object id 'c087e26a-321f-4f0c-95ae-65b5a40cf514' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/providers/read' over scope '/subscriptions/8efc1d1b-ff8c-4646-8b64-027cd8f131fc' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on provider.tf line 1, in provider "azurerm":
│    1: provider "azurerm" {
│~~~
```

Comment: Hello @Tariq, Can you please share your code as well. So that we can try from our end.

Answer (score 1):

Wihout seeing your terraform code it hard to find the exact problem,But I am assuming you might missing `client_id` and `client_secret`.

so your provider should looks something like this.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "..."
  client_id       = "..."
  client_secret   = "..."
  tenant_id       = "..."
}
```

***If you are still getting the same error after provided all the credential in provder.***

So this might your Service Principal doesn't have the Contributor role assigned to it.

Just go to the **Subscription** in the portal, select **Access Control (IAM)** and **Add the Role assignment**, **Contributor** to your **Service Principal**

Or you can follow this [***instruction***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs)

You can refer this [***StackThread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720266/terraform-unable-to-list-provider-registration-status) where the same issue another OP's encoutred.

Comment: I am using SAS token for authentication and I get the same error.