# Cannot register provider Microsoft.Kusto with Azure Resource Manager: resources.ProvidersClient#Register: Failure responding to request:StatusCode=403

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiKRq.png)

complete error : Cannot register provider Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh with Azure Resource Manager: resources.ProvidersClient#Register: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh/register/action' over scope '0000000000000000000000' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.".

with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
on backend.tf line 18, in provider "azurerm":
18: provider "azurerm"

I tried method mentioned in this but it didn't work.

[terraform plan not working with azurerm provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715849/terraform-plan-not-working-with-azurerm-provider)

https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/azure-how-to-create-iam-user-and-assign-service-principal-access/

Comment: as per the error, the spn or credentials you used doesn't have proper access to register the provider at the subscription level. Also from the code screenshot its not clear which azurerm resource you are trying to create whether its kusto or ServiceFabricMesh . Just to mention ServiceFabricMesh is retired https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-service-fabric-mesh-preview-retirement/

Answer (score 0):

> We tried to provision the sample resource using the different provider configuration mentioned. We got the required output without any error as mentioned.

Here I tried to provision a sample resource with limited access to provision to show how we provide the access as IAM user service principal access.

To achieve this we can do it in two ways.

1. Directly assigning contributor role through the portal directly till container level where we store the state file in remote location for versioning.
2. Importing Role access through CLI before executing terraform commands.

Going through the links which you're shared I hope you tried providing the access through portal.

Now try to Import the role access whenever you're working on terraform as mentioned below.

- **az login**
- **az account set --subscription 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000**
- **az role assignment create --role "Contributor" --assignee 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000 --scope "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/"**

Once you're done following steps please use the provider configuration as mentioned below.

**Note :** This is demo configuration to show the provider working fine without any fail.

```
terraform {

required_providers {

# api = {

#   source = "Azure/azapi"

# }




azapi = {

  source  = "azure/azapi"

  version = "=1.2.0"

}






azurerm = {

  source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"

  //version = "=3.0.2"

  version = "=3.57.0"

  // version = "~> 2.0.0"

}

}
  

backend  "azurerm" {

resource_group_name  =  "your_resource-group"

storage_account_name  =  "demostorageaccount"

container_name  =  "democontainer"

key  =  "terraform.tfstate"

}

}

  

provider  "azurerm" {

features {}

subscription_id  =  "000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000"

tenant_id  =  "000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000"

}

  

resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "example" {

name  =  "example-vnet"

address_space  =  ["10.0.0.0/16"]

location  =  "West US"

resource_group_name  =  "v-bolliv-Mindtree"

}
```

**Output:**

**terraform_init**

[image]

**terraform_plan**

[image]

**terraform_apply**

[image]

By this configuration we can execute all necessary terraform steps and get the desired output as we are provider access for all the provider under service principal in a targeted subscription.