# terraform error:Unable to list provider registration status with azure

Tags: azure, terraform, cloud

i was working on my small project with terraform and i am gettin gthis error when i run terraform plan : Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error.
i double checked credentials and permissions but nithing is working

double checked credentials
updated terraform
terraform init and validate run without errors

Answer (score 1):

> According to the SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720266/terraform-unable-to-list-provider-registration-status) by **Eat at Jones** You need to give your service principal atleast contributor or Owner access at the Subscription or the resource group level where you’re trying to access or create resources with Terraform.

I tried to initiate azurerm terraform resource provider without assigning it any contributor role at the Subscription or resource group level and got the same error code as yours, Refer below:-

[image]

> According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720266/terraform-unable-to-list-provider-registration-status) by **Eat at Jones** I assigned the Contributor role to the Service principal that I am using for authentication at the subscription level like below:-
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Click on Review+assign and the Contributor role will be assigned to
> the Service principal successfully.

After assigning the role, I ran the code again like below and created a resource group without any error:-

> I have used the below code from official [terraform
>
> document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720266/terraform-unable-to-list-provider-registration-status) by **Begin** to authenticate my service principal in terraform with client secrets.
>
> **Complete terraform [main.tf](http://main.tf) code:-**
>
> ```
> required_providers {
>
> azurerm  =  {
>
> source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
>
> version = "3.8.0"
>
> }
>
> }
>
> }
>
>   
>
> provider  "azurerm" {
>
> subscription_id  =  "<sub-id>"
>
> client_id  =  "<client-id>"
>
> client_secret  =  "<client-secret>"
>
> tenant_id  =  "<tenant-id>"
>
> features {}
>
> }
>
>   
>
> resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "appgrp" {
>
> name  =  "app-grp"
>
> location  =  "North Europe"
>
> }
> ```

**In terminal:-**

```
terraform plan -out main.tfplan
```

**Output:-**

[image]

```
terraform apply
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]